# Bluetooth headset 'answer button ' event read on linux system(raspberry pi)

Tags: bluetooth

I am doing a experiment in which I have raspberry pi board with linux running on it. I have a mono Bluetooth headset with.
I am able to play audio on headset using 'HSP' profile running on linux board.
I want to capture button event 'answer call' pressed on Bluetooth headset in linux board( raspberry pi)

I tried to see some stuffs on internet on this, I found Bluetooth headset sends AT command when button is pressed, but I am not able to read that AT command on raspberry pi board.

Please suggest any methods.

Thanks,
Mohan

Comment: Any luck with that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following method to bind the buttons to change tracks in mpg123 (only works when mpg123 is ran from "console", on a headless raspberry pi Zero W with apt-get conspy and screen attached)

login: pi

```
sudo loadkeys <<EOF
keycode 200 = bracketleft
keycode 201 = bracketright
keycode 165 = bracketright
keycode 163 = bracketleft
EOF

screen -S conspy.mpg123
conspy
mpg123 -Z -k 0 -@ /home/pi/.mp3z
<ctrl + A,D> to detach
```

The buttons only work to swap tracks however they do not go "previous" it just skips to another random mp3 from the -Z option passed.

Keep in mind you'll have to reload the loadkey script after boot to rebind them.
Thanks to friendofafriend@irc.freenode for the help!